# Angular FormArray custom validator not firing

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

Within my FormGroup there is a FormArray that will contain n number of FormControls, each of these FormControls has an email validator attached to it.

I want my FormArray to be able to know whether or not any of the FormControls have an email validation error, and if so the FormError errors property should be set to `{email: true}`.

To do this, I have written a custom validator that is applied to my FormArray. However this validator does not seem to be firing properly when FormControl elements are added or removed from the FormArray.

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      alertContacts: this.formBuilder.array(this.alertData.alertContacts, [Validators.required, alertContactsArrayValidator]),
    });
```

This form array is controlled by a child component that has a referenece to the formArray passed to it as an input upon instantiation. The method in the child component to add a value to the formArray is

```
  pushToFormcontrol(value: any) {
    if(!this.fArray.value.includes(value)){
      if(this.usesAutocomplete){
        if(this.autocompleteData.some(el => el === value)) {
          this.fArray.push(this.formBuilder.control(value));
          this.filterAutocomplete();
          this.clearInput();
        }
      } else {
          this.fArray.push(this.formBuilder.control(value, [Validators.email]));
          this.clearInput();
      }
    }
    this.fArray.markAsDirty();
  }
```

The custom validator for my FormArray is

```
export function alertContactsArrayValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (formArray: FormArray): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    console.log(formArray);
    let hasEmailErrors = false;
    let formControls = formArray.controls;
    console.log(formControls);
    formControls.forEach(control => {
      let controlErrors: ValidationErrors = control.errors;
      console.log("Current control errors: ", controlErrors);
      Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(key => {
        if (key === 'email') {
          hasEmailErrors = true;
          console.log("key has email");
        }
      });
    });
    return hasEmailErrors ? {email: true} : null;
  };
}
```

If I debug my code in the browser I can see that the outer alertContactsArrayValidator function is stepped into but the returned inner function is never activated. I never see any of the console logs either.

EDIT

After some further experimentation I've found something interesting. If I modify my FormArray so that I'm inserting an empty array instead of my `this.alertData.alertContacts` which is an array of strings, the validator works perfectly. I'm starting to think this is an issue with the way I'm creating the FormArray.

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      alertContacts: this.formBuilder.array([], [Validators.required, alertContactsArrayValidator]), //An empty array works fine
    });
```

If I want to instantiate my FormArray with elements already inside of it, should I be doing it in a different way than just passing the array as the first parameter of the `this.formBuilder.array()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `Validator`, `ValidatorFn` should be fired manually (Angular doesn't call it itself to let you pass in some useful configurations) as below:

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  alertContacts: this.formBuilder.array(
    this.alertData.alertContacts,
    [Validators.required, alertContactsArrayValidator()]
  ),
});
```

Edit:

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  alertContacts: this.formBuilder.array(
    this.alertData.alertContacts.map(x => new FormControl(x, [
      Validators.required,
      alertContactsArrayValidator()
    ])),
  ),
});
```

Comment: See, I tried this. But when I did it put my app into an infinite loop of errors. I've actually discovered something. I'll edit the OP.

Comment: `@Jake12342134` `FormArray` accepts an array of `FormControl`

Comment: Is there an easy way to pass a string array to the formBuilder.array method or will I need to create a method to convert a `string[]` to a `FormControl[]`?

Comment: `this.alertData.alertContacts.map(x => new FormControl(x))`

Comment: Doesn't work, I still get this strange error that causes the infinite loop.

Comment: I don't understand how this is breaking everything. If I provide the FormArray with an empty array it works fine, as soon as I give it anything else it just breaks the entire app.

Comment: are you sure this.alertData.alertContacts is defined

Comment: Yes 100%, I'm using the FormArray to control a mat-chip-list and the chips are being populated